# PHP image replacement?

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm having a brain dead moment... If someone could talk this through with me and make suggestions that'd be great.

I'm importing a URL from a database, eg `www.mysite.com/images/image1.jpg` set as variable `newimage1`

This is loaded from the DB and placed on the page.

As this is an edit page, the user can upload a new image.

If the user doesn't upload a new image, but saves the page anyway, the variable `newimage1` is not set, it clears the existing image url from the database because the variable is set to `""`.

What's the best way to do this? An if statement, that checks if `newimage1` is blank and removes it from the update to the database?

Sorry for this simple question!

Comment: Yes, If the field is empty remove from the `update` statement.

Comment: Maybe you can check the variable before update, if empty then don't update.

Comment: Have you tried something like `if(isset($_FILES['newimage1'])){//UPLOAD}`

Comment: why need to store the whole path? you can  just rename the image and store in database

Comment: Thanks guys! I'm trying `if ($image1new !="") { $image1=$image1new; }` - so the `$image1` variable is set only if a new file is uploaded & path is set in `$image1new` :) It help to talk these things out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$image_name = "";
if(!empty($_FILES)){
    $image_name = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
}

$sql = "UPDATE table SET var1 = 'value1', var2='value2'";
if($image_name != "")
    $sql .= ", image_name = '".$image_name."'";
$sql .= " WHERE id_entry = 5";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if( empty($_REQUEST['newImage1']) ) {
  //program logic
} else {
  //program logic
}
```