# php update database with image url, but don't overwrite existing value?

Tags: php, if-statement

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP image replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125580/php-image-replacement)

I'm writing an edit script that allows a row to be updated in the database.

It starts by importing that row, then I wrap input boxes around the text areas which can be edited and updated.

That works great.

There are two url's stored in the database, `http://www.mysite.com/images/image1.jpg` and `http://www.mysite.com/images/image2.jpg`

What's the best way of checking if there are no new uploaded images on the edit form, to NOT update this field in the database?

I've tried using:

```
if ($image1new !="") { $image1==$image1new; } else { $image1 = $_POST['image1'];}
if ($image2new !="") { $image2==$image2new; } else { $image2 = $_POST['image2'];}
```

But that always passes a blank string?

Comment: Where are you setting `$image1new` & `$image2new`

Comment: because the uploader needs a variable to upload to. I thought that if no string was passed from the uploader script, it would auto set the $image1 to blank, as no value is passed to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `$image1 = $image1new;`  instead of `$image1 == $image1new;`. You should use just a **single** `=` when you want to assign a value to a variable

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want check if the input file have a file uploaded, and store that in DB, right?

First you need to retrieve, and store the ID of row in a variable, will assume that u will store that value in a variable called $id...

So I think u can try that:

```
if (isset($_FILES["input_file_name"]) {
$file = $_FILES["input_file_name"];

mysql_connect("server","user","pass") or die("Cannot access DB");

$sql_cmd = "UPDADE `database`.`table` SET `column` = '".$file."' WHERE `id` = ".$id.";";
mysql_query($sql_cmd);

}

else {
echo 'No images to store.';
}
```

Hope this can help.